# Volume of a region bounded by two paraboloids

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find the volume of the region between paraboloids $z=5-x^2-y^2$ and $z=x^2+y^2+1$

I know that the upper surface bounding the solid is $z=5-x^2-y^2$ and that the lower surface is $z=x^2+y^2+1$. If I set the two equal to each other and solve for z:

$$x^2+y^2+1 = 5-x^2-y^2$$

$z=3$

and $x^2+y^2=2$ ,which is a circle of radius $\sqrt{2}$

I follow through by setting up my region

$$R{ (x,y): -\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-{x^2}}} ≤y≤\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-{x^2}},-\sqrt{2}≤x≤\sqrt{2}$$

So I set up my iterated integral and attempt to solve. Multiplying the final answer by four since the volume of the entire solid is four times the volume over that part of R in the first quadrant.

$$4\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-{x^2}}} (5-x^2-y^2) - (x^2+y^2+1) dydx$$

Which simplifies to

$$8\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-{x^2}}} 2-x^2-y^2 dydx$$

But I'm not confident in the upper bound I calculated for the y region. Is there an error in my arithmetic or something I'm missing in particular? If not, how do you solve such an integral?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is easier to do in cylindrical coordinates, to take advantage of the symmetry. In this case the bounds become $0 \le r \le \sqrt{2}$ and any $\theta.$ The area element in the $r,\theta$ plane is $r dr d\theta,$ and the bounds on $z$ go from $r^2+1$ to $5-r^2.$ So subtracting lower from upper means the integral for volume is that of the function $h(r,\theta)=r(4-2r^2),$ with the $r,\theta$ region just described above.

Noting that there is no $\theta$ in the integrand $r(4-2r^2),$ the double integral is actually 
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^rr(4-2r^2)\ dr\ d\theta.$$
[It would have originally been a triple integral, with a $dz$ and $z$ going from $r^2+1$ up to $5-r^2,$ but that inner integral just gives the factor $4-2r^2$ in the above. Note that the extra factor of $r$ is because of the polar coordinate area element $rdrd\theta.$]

Comment: Do you mind writing out this double integral? The wording has me thrown off a little bit. I've learned about transforming a function of x and y into r and $\theta$ and how it makes such a computation much easier, but setting it up is always the hardest part. I modified my original post to show how I set it up

Comment: @user3487243 Just put that integral in. $\theta$ must go $0$ to $2\pi$ because of the symmetry.